# WPF AutocompeteBox in datagrid Cell does not work properly

Tags: wpf, datagrid, autocomplete

I am testing the WPF AutoCompleteBox control in datagrid cell.
I met two problems:

1) when i navigate to the autocomplete cell , it does not automatically switch to edit mode,

2) When I switch into edit mode and  I type something, the list of suggesstions doesn’t  appears and I after closing the window, i have a debug error that says :

*System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Names' property not found on 'object' ''Person' (HashCode=40808136)'. BindingExpression:Path=Names; DataItem='Person' (HashCode=40808136); target element is 'AutoCompleteBox' (Name='acb2'); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')*

Here The code

```
namespace WpfPlayingWithDatagrid
{
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MyViewModel mv = new MyViewModel();
        this.DataContext = mv;


    }
}
}

public class MyViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    ObservableCollection<Person> _names = null;

    RelayCommand _loadClients;
    RelayCommand _showSelectedPerson;

    Person _selectedPerson;

    public Person SelectedPerson
    {
        get { return _selectedPerson; }
        set { _selectedPerson = value; }
    }



    public ObservableCollection<Person> Names
    {
        get { return _names; }
        set { _names = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("Names");
        }
    }


    public RelayCommand LoadClientCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_loadClients == null)
                _loadClients = new RelayCommand(LoadCommandExecute);
            return _loadClients;
        }
    }



    private void LoadCommandExecute()
    {
        LoadClients();
    }



    public void LoadClients()
    {
        List<Person> ll = new List<Person>(5);
        ll.Add(new Person(1,"ETS CUSTOMER1","Addresse1"));
        ll.Add(new Person(2,"COMPX CUSTOMER2","Addresse 2"));
        ll.Add(new Person(3,"ENTREPRISE3","Adresse3"));
        ll.Add(new Person(4,"SOCIETE X4HERTZ","Addresse4"));
        ll.Add(new Person(5,"CARCOMP","Addresse5"));

        Names   = new ObservableCollection<Person>(ll);

    }



    public RelayCommand ShowSelectedPersonCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_showSelectedPerson == null)
                _showSelectedPerson = new RelayCommand(ShowSelectedPersonCommandExecute);
            return _showSelectedPerson;
        }
    }



    private void ShowSelectedPersonCommandExecute()
    {
        if (SelectedPerson != null)
                        MessageBox.Show(SelectedPerson.Nom);
        else
            MessageBox.Show("No selection.");

    }

}}
```

and The XAML is as follows :

```
<Window x:Class="WpfPlayingWithDatagrid.MainWindow"
    x:Name="wnd"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:gs="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Input.Toolkit"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfPlayingWithDatagrid"
    Title="MainWindow" >

<Window.Resources>
    <local:MyViewModel x:Key="MyViewModel"/>

    <Style x:Key="acbStyle" TargetType="controls:AutoCompleteBox">
        <Setter Property="FilterMode" Value="Contains"/>
        <Setter Property="IsTextCompletionEnabled" Value="True"/>
    </Style> 
    <DataTemplate x:Key="AutoCompleteBoxItemTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Content="{Binding Code}"  Width="20" />
            <Label Content="{Binding Nom}"/>
         </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Column="1" 
                Content="Load Customers" 
                Command="{Binding LoadClientCommand}" Margin="10"/>
                <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" 
                          Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                          AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                          VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  
                          RowHeight="30"
                          Grid.Column="0" 
                          SelectionUnit="Cell"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding  Names, 
                      UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                         Grid.RowSpan="2"
                >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn 
             Binding="{Binding Code,  Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat=\{0:#\}}"  Header="Code" />
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name" >

               <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Nom}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <controls:AutoCompleteBox
                                x:Name="acb2"
                                Text="{Binding Nom}" 
                                ItemsSource="{Binding Names}"  
                                ValueMemberBinding="{Binding Nom}"
                                Style="{StaticResource acbStyle}"
                                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource AutoCompleteBoxItemTemplate}"
                                />
                        </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>

        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
       <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Adresse, Mode=TwoWay,      UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"       Header="Adresse" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
      </Grid>
     </Window>
```

and Person class :

```
 namespace WpfPlayingWithDatagrid
{
  public class Person
  {
    int code;

    public int Code
    {
        get { return code; }
        set { code = value; }
    }
    string nom;

    public string Nom
    {
        get { return nom; }
        set { nom = value; }
    }
    string adresse;

    public string Adresse
    {
        get { return adresse; }
        set { adresse = value; }
    }



    public Person(int c, string n, string a)
    {
        Code = c;
        Nom = n;
        Adresse = a;

    }
}
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the way DataGridColumns are implemented, binding to parent viewmodels are always problematic.

The reason you are getting the binding error is because the row is bound to Person, and Person does not have the Names property.

The names property occur on MyViewModel and can be accessed like this

```
<controls:AutoCompleteBox
  x:Name="acb2"
  Text="{Binding Nom}" 
  ItemsSource="{Binding Names,Source={StaticResource MyViewModel}}"  
  ValueMemberBinding="{Binding Nom}"
  Style="{StaticResource acbStyle}"
  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource AutoCompleteBoxItemTemplate}"
 />
```

**Updated**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MyViewModel mv = (MyViewModel) FindResource("MyViewModel");
        this.DataContext = mv;

    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it before , but still does not work. I think i have t find a way to access the datacontext from the autcompletebox cell.

Comment: Sorry Chui Tey, I wrote the comment before your update, so I did not see it. Now it works fine

Comment: What about the edit mode ?, can i enter directly in edit mode without mouse double click ?